# URL Issues in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a decent history with CakePHP 1.3, but am working on my first 2.x (2.3, in this case) app and have bumped into what *appears* to be a couple of odd issues with URL generation that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

1. I have a form that I'd like to submit to the same action with a different extension (`.csv`).  To do so, I tried:

   ```
   # FYI, $this->here = /admin/activities/index
   $this->Form->create('Activity', 
     array( 'admin' => true, 'controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'csv' )
   ```

   What I get as my form action is `action=".csv"`.
2. As a possible workaround, I tried simply setting the url as a string -- `'url' => '/admin/activities/index.csv'`. Now the form `action` looks right, but when I submit the form I get an error.

   ```
   Error: The action admin_index.csv is not defined in controller ActivitiesController
   ```

What am I missing here? I've read through the 2.3 FormHelper & Router docs as well as the migration docs for each version I've "skipped" (2.1, 2.2, 2.3) and I don't see anything that jumps out at me, but it wouldn't be the first time I've missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have mentioned in #2 is not a workaround but rather the proper way to specify a url. The error you get is probably because you are missing `Router::parseExtensions()` in your routes.php

Edit, just to be clear this is what your Form->create() should look like.

```
$this->Form->create('Activity', 
  array('url' => array(
     'admin' => true, 'controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'csv'
  ))
);
```

and add `Router::parseExtensions()` or `Router::parseExtensions('csv')` if you only want to parse .csv extensions to your routes.php

Comment: Damn. I knew it would be something simple. I enabled the `admin` routing prefix, but completely failed to enable extension parsing. Thanks, man. Also, I didn't realize that #2 was preferred to the array syntax.